# along or along with?

Tags: grammar

> I performed along musicians from Italy, Japan, America.

I saw the above and was wondering if it was an error, because it should be "along with" and not "along". What do you think? Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct that it's an error.  You could say "along with musicians from..." or better, "alongside" to clarify that you performed at the same time as time as them. However, if you're writing rather than speaking, the most succinct way to say it is:

> I performed with musicians from Italy, Japan, and America.

Comment: Alongside is also possible. Perhaps better if the meaning is playing together (as in an orchestra).